# Add a break to a bar chart when one value is very large

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if someone could reproduce such a figure in ggplot? It is about controlling the height of a bar when one value is very large compared to the rest of the observations so as if plotted as usual, the figure would lose in readability.

I attached a copy of the figure plus the data.

```
    oecd_struct <-
  structure(
    list(
      Country = c(
        "Australia",
        "Austria",
        "Belgium",
        "Canada",
        "Chile",
        "Colombia",
        "Costa Rica",
        "Czech Republic",
        "Denmark",
        "Estonia",
        "Finland",
        "France",
        "Germany",
        "Greece",
        "Hungary",
        "Iceland",
        "Ireland",
        "Israel",
        "Italy",
        "Japan",
        "Korea",
        "Latvia",
        "Lithuania",
        "Luxembourg",
        "Mexico",
        "Netherlands",
        "New Zealand",
        "Norway",
        "Poland",
        "Portugal",
        "Slovak Republic",
        "Slovenia",
        "Spain",
        "Sweden",
        "Switzerland",
        "Turkey",
        "United Kingdom",
        "United States",
        "Euro area (19 countries)",
        "European Union – 27 countries (from 01/02/2020)",
        "G7",
        "OECD - Europe",
        "G20",
        "OECD - Total"
      ),
      `Mar-2022` = c(
        NA,
        6.771345,
        8.30694,
        6.661891,
        9.408826,
        8.532487,
        5.793175,
        12.74165,
        5.369128,
        15.18811,
        5.797654,
        4.482269,
        7.255814,
        8.850036,
        8.5,
        6.66674,
        6.718598,
        3.479125,
        6.460945,
        1.2,
        4.143755,
        11.47688,
        15.72477,
        6.140189,
        7.453677,
        9.727198,
        NA,
        4.537522,
        11,
        5.33119,
        10.39687,
        5.363471,
        9.818375,
        5.966897,
        2.386192,
        61.14454,
        6.2,
        8.542456,
        7.4,
        7.8,
        7.054284,
        11.62023,
        7.900509,
        8.76883
      ),
      `Apr-2022` = c(
        NA,
        7.170923,
        8.306277,
        6.771204,
        10.51613,
        9.233481,
        7.151562,
        14.16084,
        6.685769,
        18.88015,
        5.738172,
        4.82713,
        7.393715,
        10.17281,
        9.5,
        7.23057,
        6.96325,
        3.964321,
        5.955812,
        2.5,
        4.775446,
        12.99162,
        16.83821,
        6.959978,
        7.682503,
        9.555596,
        NA,
        5.391304,
        12.4,
        7.204314,
        11.71221,
        6.947867,
        8.344685,
        6.360725,
        2.548044,
        69.97107,
        7.8,
        8.25863,
        7.4,
        8.1,
        7.144573,
        12.64813,
        8.510648,
        9.178216
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -44L)
  )
```

[image: Figur to reproduce]

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten Code updated.

Answer (score 4):

Basically one option to "break" the bar with a high value would be to use an upper bound for this value when plotting the bars.

To add the "break" you could use e.g. `annotate` to add a polygon and two segments to indicate the break which requires some fiddling to set the x and y coordinates.

```r
df <- oecd_struct
colnames(df) <- c("cntry", "mar22", "infl")

df$infl = df$infl / 100

max_infl <- .2

df$infl_trim <- pmin(df$infl, max_infl)
df$cntry <- reorder(df$cntry, df$infl)
df <- df[!is.na(df$infl),]

pos_break <- which(levels(df$cntry) == "Turkey")
bar_width <- .6

yhi <- pos_break + bar_width / 2 + .1
ylo <- pos_break - bar_width / 2 - .1
xlo <- max_infl - c(.015, .01)
xhi <- max_infl - c(.01, .005)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(infl_trim, cntry)) +
  geom_col(width = bar_width) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::label_percent(accuracy = .1)(infl)), hjust = -.1, size = 8 / .pt) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)), labels = scales::label_percent(), position = "top") +
  annotate("polygon", x = c(xlo, rev(xhi)), y = c(ylo, ylo, yhi, yhi), fill = "white", color = NA) +
  annotate("segment", x = xlo, xend = xhi, y = ylo, yend = yhi, size = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

**EDIT** As I found this a challenging question I wrapped the code to add the breaks in a function with some "sensible" chosen defaults to avoid the fiddling with the coordinates. Additionally I generalized the function so that it now allows to add multiple breaks. Still not ideal but the next step to perhaps build a real "Geom".

```
df <- oecd_struct

colnames(df) <- c("cntry", "mar22", "apr22")

max_infl <- 20

df$cntry <- gsub("\\s?\\(.+?\\)", "", df$cntry)
df$apr22_trim <- pmin(df$apr22, max_infl)
df$mar22_trim <- ifelse(df$mar22 > max_infl, NA, df$mar22)
df$cntry <- reorder(df$cntry, df$apr22)
df <- df[!is.na(df$apr22),]

add_breaks <- function(df, x, y, x_trim, max.x, bar.width, fill, break.width = .025) {
  pos_breaks <- which(df[[x]] > df[[x_trim]])
  pos_breaks <- which(levels(df[[y]]) %in% df[[y]][pos_breaks])
  
  lapply(pos_breaks, function(x) {
    yhi <- x + bar.width / 2 + .1
    ylo <- x - bar.width / 2 - .1
    xlo <- max.x - c(.06 * max.x, .04 * max.x)
    xhi <- max.x - c(.04 * max.x, .02 * max.x)
    
    list(
      ggplot2::annotate("polygon", x = c(xlo, rev(xhi)), y = c(ylo, ylo, yhi, yhi), fill = fill, color = NA),
      ggplot2::annotate("segment", x = xlo, xend = xhi, y = ylo, yend = yhi, size = 1)
    )   
  })
}


library(ggplot2)

fill_bg <- "#D1F2E9"
fill_col <- "#01967B"
color_pt <-  "#FFC00D"
bar_width <- .6

ggplot(df, aes(apr22_trim, cntry)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = "apr22"), width = bar_width) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mar22_trim, color = "mar22"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::number(apr22, accuracy = .1)), hjust = -.2, size = 8 / .pt) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)), position = "top") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(mar22 =color_pt), labels = c(mar22 = "March 2022"), guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(apr22 = fill_col), labels = c(apr22 = "April 2022"), guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  add_breaks(df, x = "apr22", y = "cntry", x_trim = "apr22_trim", max.x = max_infl, bar.width = bar_width, fill = fill_bg) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = fill_bg),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = fill_bg),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = fill_bg),
        legend.justification = "left",
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = fill_bg),
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, color = NULL, fill = NULL,
       title = "Inflation Rate, April 2022", subtitle = "Percentage Change over same period previous year")
```

[image]

Comment: So i guess there is no programatically savvy way to do it. Your solution gives the expected result, but as you mentioned it requires some fiddling with the data prior to plotting :)